# Angular-FusionCharts dynamic chart creation: chartobject-1.render() Error >> Unable to find the container DOM element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, fusioncharts

I'm using Ionic 2 and Angular to build an app and want to show some charts. So, I fetch data from a server and loop through the result. However, first chart doesn't render and gives me the following error:
`EXCEPTION: #03091456 chartobject-1.render() Error >> Unable to find the container DOM element.` But, when I debug it via Chrome Debugger, I can see the container element. Yet, fusioncharts is somehow unable to detect it. What can be the problem and how can I solve this?

My template file is this.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let chart of charts">
    <fusioncharts width="100%" height="50%" 
                  type={{chart.type}}
                  dataFormat="JSON" 
                  [dataSource]=chart.dataSource>
    </fusioncharts>
</ion-card>
```

UPDATE: If I delete `enableProdMode()`, none of the charts are getting rendered.

UPDATE: Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/jOSb4ILhHW1Nh4eI5Mtk?p=preview

Comment: Due to Syntax may be?  Try quotes instead of angular braces.                                                                                    `<ion-card *ngFor="let chart of charts">
    <fusioncharts width="100%" height="50%" 
                  type="chart.type"
                  dataFormat="JSON" 
                  [dataSource]="chart.dataSource">
    </fusioncharts>
</ion-card>`

Comment: I don't think so. Because second chart is getting rendered. If the syntax is the case, then it should not be rendered as well.